# Overfull hbox Footer Beamer

Tags: beamer, footer

I am getting crazy of debugging an overfull hbox in my beamer presentation. The footer constantly produces the following message:

```
Overfull \hbox (456.8095pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active
```

The template I have got is several hundred lines long and I could not manage to find a minimum working example (sorry!)
But I found out where the problem is and maybe somebody understands the cause of it.

Its within the footer in those lines:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{decolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  % Page number.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=0ex,center]{}%
    \usebeamerfont{palette primary}\insertframenumber{} \beamer@decolines@pageofpages{} \inserttotalframenumber%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=0ex]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % First line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Second line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  % Third line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}%
```

It looks like that:
[image]

It basically produces three lines:
The first line containing the page number, the second one containing that long blue line and the third one that yellow one.

I do understand that changing the length of those wd-parameters changes the amount of "overfullness", but I could not find any way of solving it.

Is there somebody out here who understands the code (even without an example) and can guess a solution for it?

Comment: that code is making a paragraph consisting of three boxes each \paperwidth wide separated by word spaces, so it probably wraps to a three line paragraph \paperwidth wide, but what size box are you placing this in, what does `\showthe\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth\relax` show?

Comment: The output of that command is: > 54.62704pt.
l.109 \showthe\dimexpr\paperwidth-\textwidth\relax

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using a theme based on the Torino theme. This theme is missing empty lines or `\par`'s in the footline. You can repair it like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\usetheme{Torino}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \leavevmode%
  % Page number.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=0ex,center]{}%
    \usebeamerfont{palette primary}\insertframenumber{} \beamer@decolines@pageofpages{} \inserttotalframenumber%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=0ex]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %

  % First line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.2\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.8\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@lineup,dp=0pt]{lineup}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  
  % Second line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linemid,dp=0pt]{linemid}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  } %
  
  % Third line.
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.9\paperwidth,ht=\beamer@decolines@linebottom,dp=0pt]{linebottom}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]