Page numbers too low in beamer theme 'Torino'
I have the problem that the page numbers in the Beamer theme 'Torino' are a bit too far down. They are slightly covered by the first of the two green lines at the bottom. How can I move the page numbers up a bit so that they don't interfere with the first green line at the bottom?
Here is a minimal example:
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme[pageofpages=of,% String used between the current page and the
                         % total page count.
          bullet=circle,% Use circles instead of squares for bullets.
          titleline=true,% Show a line below the frame title.
          alternativetitlepage=true,% Use the fancy title page.
          titlepagelogo=siegel,% Logo for the first page.
          watermark=watermark-polito,% Watermark used in every page.
          watermarkheight=100px,% Height of the watermark.
          watermarkheightmult=4,% The watermark image is 4 times bigger
                                % than watermarkheight.
          ]{Torino}
                    
\author{John Doe}
\title{Some title}
\institute{Some institute}
\date{15th June 2024}

\newcommand{\backupbegin}{
   \newcounter{finalframe}
   \setcounter{finalframe}{\value{framenumber}}
}
\newcommand{\backupend}{
   \setcounter{framenumber}{\value{finalframe}}
}   

\begin{document}

\small
\watermarkoff

\begin{frame}[t,plain]
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{Some title}
Some content
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]{}
\begin{center}
\vspace{3.2cm}
{\Huge \textcolor{OliveGreen}{Thank you for your attention!}}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}

The second page of the produced PDF file looks like this:


Duplicate https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/650610/36296
